# Mongoose query is taking too long in mqtt on_message callback

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I have a Mqtt client subscribing to a topic. When the subscriber receives message, the on_message callback starts working. I have a mongoose query based on the message inside the on_message callback. That query is taking too long to execute.

However, keeping the query outside the on_message callback executes immediately. But I want it inside the callback.

Here is my code sample -

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

mqttClient  = mqtt.connect("mqtt://broker.emqx.io:1883",{clientId:"mqttClient", keepalive: 1000});

let options = {
    retain:false,
    qos:1};


mqttClient.subscribe('topic' ,{qos:1});
mqttClient.on('message', async function (topic, message){
    let msg = JSON.parse(message); 
    msg.forEach(async letter => {

    let dev = await Device.find({
        letters: letter}).lean();
  })
});

mqttClient.publish('topic', JSON.stringify(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']), options);
```

here, `dev` query is the one taking too long.

Comment: I doubt it matters where the query is executed. How do you conclude that it's a) taking too long inside the callback and b) it's faster outside the callback?

Comment: @robertklep I'd say both the cases but for your understanding, I go with a) taking too long inside the callback. I have to wait about 10s.

Comment: The short answer is that you should not be starting long running tasks in the callback at all. If you have long running tasks they should be farmed out to a thread pool (or since this is NodeJS you should not be using await, but using a callback so it doesn't block) so the callback can return as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hardillb suggested, I removed the query from the callback and queried somewhere else. Using query callback also does not help, it is still taking too long. I strongly believe it is because of mongoose. Because I tried the same with mongodb and it is more faster as the usual query would behave.